# Django template does not exist?

Tags: django, django-templates

When I am trying to deploy to railway my project, i get the error mentioned above. This is one log that could give more insight?
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/client/client/public/index.html (Source does not exist)

Here is my `project.settings.py` file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client')
      ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME': 'game-api',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'PORT': 5432
    }
}


ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

`project.views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'build/index.html')
```

My files:

[image]

Comment: does source exists? `/app/client/client/public/index.html` folder collapsed in your screenshot

Comment: Ignore the log i sent you, apologies. That is incorrect because it was older log and thats not how its set up in the code i provided. Here is the log:

`django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/client/build/index.html (Source does not exist)`

These are all of the files that I have name of the folder where the backend and front end is located is `project-4-api` and `client` folder is my front end.

Comment: Could you potentially check my github repo? Im sure you will get more clarity on my code... https://github.com/rokster112/project-4-api

Comment: try to change `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client')]` to `'DIRS': []`

Comment: Did not help unfortunately :/